# SDL2 module not found

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm using python 3.7.9 and I have this code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And I get this error:
[image: This is the error I get]
Yes, I've tried reinstalling all kivy libraries multiple times, I've tried reinstalling Python but I still get this error.

My project settings:
[image: Project settings]
My configurations:
[image: configurations]

I've even found it in 'External Libraries' folder:
[image: External Libraries]

I've tried to fix for literally 3 hours now and I'm too frustrated so I'm asking you guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think kivy and pycharm work regularly, it's easier with regular python compiler

Answer (score 0):

First, forget pycharm, follow the kivy install instructions and see if you can run a kivy app via python from the command line. If you can't, debug this without the pycharm environments getting in the way.

If you can install and run kivy outside of pycharm, then your only problem is that you haven't installed it correctly within whatever python environment pycharm is using. I don't know how you configure it, but you'd need to make sure kivy and its dependencies are installed in that environment.